# Make custom Navigation Buttons glow when touched?

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

In my navigation bar I have two right button bar items.  One is a custom button and the other uses the info light button type.  Both work great but I would like to make the custom button have the default glow the same way the info button does when you touch it.  Is this possible?

```
// Default info light btn
UIButton *infoBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
UIBarButtonItem *infoBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infoBtn];

// Custom Btn
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, btnImage.size.width, btnImage.size.height)];
[customButton setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rightDrawerButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:wlButton];

NSArray *rightBtns = @[customButtonItem, infoBtnItem];
[navItem setRightBarButtonItems:rightBtns animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to put one more line of code like:-

```
customButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = TRUE;
```

After this your code Output something like this:-

[image]